# Translations are normal subgroup of Space Group: Dresselhaus's proof not convincing

Tags: condensed-matter, group-theory, crystals

In [Group Theory: Applications to the physics of condensed matter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642069452), eq. 9.15, Dresselhaus gives the following proof that the translation group is a normal subgroup of the space group:
\begin{align*}
\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}\{I|t\}\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}^{-1} = \{I|R_{\alpha}t\}
\end{align*}
However, if the space group is non-symmorphic, then it could be the case that $\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}$ cannot be factored as $\{I|\tau\}\{R_{\alpha}|0\}$, where $\{I|\tau\}$ is an element of the translation group and $\{R_{\alpha}|0\}$ is an element of the space group.

If $\{I|\tau\}$ is not an element of the translation group (i.e. is a non-symmorphic translation vector), there is no problem, but what if $\{R_{\alpha}|0\}$ is not an element of the space group? Then it is not necessarily the case that $\{I|R_{\alpha}t\}$ is an element of the translation group.

So Dresselhaus's proof requires that for all non-symmorphic space group elements $\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}$, $\{\mathbf{I}|R_{\alpha}\mathfrak{t}\}$ is an element of the translation group for all $\mathfrak{t}$ in the translation group.

Is this true and what is the proof?

Comment: the space group should be a semi direct product of the group of translation and the point group and so it should factor.

Comment: I want a proof that the space group is in fact the semidirect product of the translation and point group.

Comment: a sketch of the proof has been added to answer

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: The point group is not a subgroup nor even a subset of the space group in the presence of non-symmorphic operations, and hence the space group is not a semidirect product of the translation and point group. This is shown in Glazer, Space groups for Solid State Scientists.

Answer (score 2):

I have also put some thought into the question how to show that all *primitive
translations* are a *normal subgroup* of a space group $\mathcal{G}$, in particular, of a
non-symmorphic space group which excludes the route via semidirect products.

First, the OP says correctly that the factoring into translational and
rotational ops is not possible for non-symmorphic space groups. However,
Dresselhaus never stated or implicitly used this.

Also Dresselhaus did not say that $\{I|\tau\}$ for $\tau$ being non-primitive is an element of the translation group.

I struggled as the OP with the fact that $\{I|R_{\alpha}t\}$ is in general an
element of the translation group for all possible occuring $R_\alpha$ of non-symmorphic space groups.

However, I could resolve this as following.

One should remind her-/himself in this context about
following two important points which Dresselhaus did not mention explicitly in
this paragraph but which IMHO should have been done:

1. *All space groups are subgroups of the Euclidean group $E$*, i.e. group of
   isometries (distance-preserving transformations): $|g_i x| = |x| \quad \forall
   g_i\in E, x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean length.
   Since any translational part $\tau$ (primitive or non-primitive) does not
   change lengths, all matrix parts $R_\alpha$ can also not change lengths. This has the consequence that
   $$ |R_\alpha t| = |t|.$$
2. *Closure* and existence of inverses for any mathematical group means the RHS
   of eq. (9.15) is necessarily an element of the space group $\mathcal{G}$ under
   consideration again:
   $$ gh \in \mathcal{G} \quad \forall g,h\in  \mathcal{G}$$
   $$ g^{-1}  \in \mathcal{G} \quad \forall g\in  \mathcal{G}$$
   $$ \Rightarrow ghg^{-1} = h' \in \mathcal{G}$$
   Together with point 1 we should be assured that $\{I|R_{\alpha}t\}$ is an element of  $T$: 
   1) rotational part is the identity (see below for full eq. (9.15)),
   2) the translational part has the length of a primitive translational vector (distance-preserving ops), and
   3) it is an element of the space group (closure).

Therefore, the answer is *yes*: also for all non-symmorphic space groups
$\{\mathbf{I}|R_{\alpha}t\}$ is an element of
the translation group for all $t$ in the translation group and all $R_\alpha$ of the space group.

I think the recent book by [Hergert and Geilhufe (2018)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Group+Theory+in+Solid+State+Physics+and+Photonics%3A+Problem+Solving+with+Mathematica-p-9783527411337) is a little bit better at explaining this (Section 4.2.2, p. 63).
However, I am not happy about other parts of this book.

For others who might not have all the details, I want to add the complete eq. (9.15) which shows that the translational part, denoted by $\tau$, of a general space group
element $\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}$ *cancels out* when calculating the
conjugate element for any $\{\mathbf{I}|t\}$. Previous formulas for composition and inverse of Seitz symbols, which are used in eq. (9.15), are
$$ \{\beta|\tau'^{-1}\}\{\alpha|\tau^{-1}\} = \{\beta\alpha|-\beta\tau+\tau'\} \qquad (9.4)$$
$$ \{\alpha|\tau\}^{-1} = \{\alpha^{-1}|-\alpha^{-1}\tau\} \qquad (9.7)$$

The complete eq (9.15) is:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}\{I|t\}\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}^{-1} &=& \{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}\{I|t\}\{R_{\alpha}^{-1}|-R_\alpha^{-1}\tau\}\\
&=&\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\} \{R_{\alpha}^{-1}|-R_\alpha^{-1}\tau+t\}\\
&=& \{I|-R_\alpha R_\alpha^{-1}\tau+R_\alpha t + \tau\}\\
&=& \{I|R_{\alpha}t\}
\end{eqnarray}

The cancellation occurs from the third to the fourth and final line.

Answer (score 0):

One way of proving a group $T $  is normal in group $G$ is by providing a homomorphism $\phi$ on $G$ whose kernel is T i.e $\text{ker}(\phi) = T$. So let $H$ be the point group of certain space group $G$ and let $\phi$ be the homomorphism:
$G \rightarrow H $.

A general space group element,$g$, has the general action of $ g(x) = E x + v$ on a point x . where $E$ is a matrix from the point group So let $ \phi : g \longmapsto E $
The kernel of this map are the translations. So the translations form a normal subgroup.

A way of seeing that the space group $ G $ is a semi-direct product of translations and the point group is to note the following: we have already proved that the translation group is a normal subgroup. Now all we need to note is that for the translation group $T$ and the point group $H$,  $T\cap H = \{ e\} $. It is a theorem that that is equivalent to saying $ G = T \rtimes H $

Comment: We have not already proved that the translation group is a normal subgroup. That is the content of the question.

Comment: @user14717 I did, that is the content of the first paragraph

Comment: You did not. You must exhibit the homomorphism explicitly to prove the claim.

Comment: @user14717, you can make the proof as neat and tidy as you want but the basic idea is to simply return point group part of the action of space group element. you can prove that this a homomorphism and you are on your way.

Comment: $\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}\{I|t\}\{R_{\alpha}|\tau\}^{-1}$ is in the kernel of your homomorphism, but $\{I|\mathbf{A}\mathfrak{t}\}$ might not be a translation vector of the crystal. This means the kernel of the homomorphism is too big!